# Passing a url param to a search form

Tags: php, forms, parameters

Exact problem: Trying to pass a param from the url to a search box destination page.

The param is "subid" this way:

http://www.domain.com/?subid=3456

and the current (non working) search form code in php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://search.yahoo.com/search?subid=<?php print $_GET['subid'];?>&" target="_blank" id="search-box">
  <input type="text" name="p" size="31" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I can see with firebug that the subid is in the form action when I go here:

http://www.domain.com/?subid=3456

but when I run a query in the form, is not passing to yahoo.

so where is the problem?

Comment: do u want to send para to  yahoo  url ?

Comment: What if you change it to `action=http://search.yahoo.com/search` and make a new input `<input type="hidden" name="subid" value="<?php print $_GET['subid'];?>" />`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should post `subid` as a parameter also, and specify method as `get`.

```
<form action="http://search.yahoo.com/search" target="_blank" method="get" id="search-box">
  <input type="hidden" name="subid" value="<?php print $_GET['subid'];?>" />
  <input type="text" name="p" size="31" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: And just don't do it like this value="<?php print $_GET['subid'];?>", you can make it available for XSS attacks.

Comment: Yeah, and for a start you just don't mix PHP and HTML, but use some templating, but my answer is a simple solution for the question, keeping the answer in the same manner of the question. Imagine if I answered with a huge smarty implementation...

Comment: This comment was for author of the topic :)

Comment: Awesome user2270404, thanks so much.

dikirill, can you please post an answer with your solution?
Don´t like the idea of being vulnerable to attacks.

Answer (score 0):

As was asked by the author, added some filtering for GET parameter:

```
<form action="http://search.yahoo.com/search" target="_blank" method="get" id="search-box">
  <input type="hidden" name="subid" value="<?=(int)$_GET['subid']?>" />
  <input type="text" name="p" size="31" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Or you can use `strip_tags` + `htmlentities` functions, before output.